# Is there a way to catch event when all nested transition are finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to catch the event when all the nested transitions are over. For example, I have a string as a child, after splitting it into words, and then each word into characters, I'm trying to animate each character. For that, I wrap all characters in each word with `<Transition>`. But I need to catch the event when all the characters in every single word are done with transition animation. At the moment `onExited` event fires right after the animation starts.

In the code below, I need to find a way to set `this.state.showHeadline` to true when all character are done with animation.

Link to [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/508m2z3zz4?fontsize=14)

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Transition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Content = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Word = styled.span`
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
`;
const Char = styled.span`
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 8px;
  color: black;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 4.5s, filter 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  webkit-text-stroke: 0.45px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  transform: perspective(1050px) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.9);
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;

  ${props =>
    props.state &&
    ((props.state === "entering" &&
      css`
        opacity: 0;
      `) ||
      (props.state === "entered" &&
        css`
          opacity: 1;
        `))}
`;

class TextWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showTitle: false,
      showHeadline: false
    };
  }

  setState(state) {
    super.setState(state);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          showTitle: true
        };
      }),
      1000
    );
  }

  render() {
    const content = this.props.children.split(" ").map((word, i) => {
      const chars = word.split("").map((char, i, charArray) => {
        return (
          <Transition
            in={this.state.showTitle}
            timeout={(i + 0.5) * 400}
            key={char + i}
          >
            {state => <Char state={state}>{char}</Char>}
          </Transition>
        );
      });
      return (
        <Transition key={i} timeout={0}>
          <Word>
            <TransitionGroup
              appear={true}
              component={null}
              onEntered={console.log("char")}
            >
              {chars}
            </TransitionGroup>
          </Word>
        </Transition>
      );
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Content>
          <TransitionGroup appear={true} component={null} onExited={null}>
            {content}
          </TransitionGroup>
        </Content>
        {this.state.showHeadline && <Content>Hello</Content>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => <TextWrapper>Example Text</TextWrapper>;

const root = document.getElementById("app");
if (root) {
  render(<App />, root);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be done with redux.

Comment: @lakerskill I haven't used Redux yet but I would appreciate if you could show how.

Comment: Unfortunately redux is an entire beast on it's own.  The docs are great for this, but also, it can be quite complicated.  While redux may be best for this situation, it probably won't be as widely used with the inclusion of hooks.  https://redux.js.org for the docs.  Might still be worth learning just because I'm sure it's in a lot of places code.

Comment: @lakerskill Thanks, will do.

Comment: Anytime, don't be afraid to ask questions once you get there.  Redux is tough at first, but really easy after you learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `redux`.

Because your `CSS` is handling animation timings, they'll always be delayed from the `state` that the character's `Transition` is in. So you would do several things:

1. Determine the length of the `string`.
2. Track all characters that have entered into an `entered` state via their `onEntered` event handler. This handler takes a callback function that adds to `keysLoaded` state.
3. Compare the length of the `keysLoaded` state to the `stringLength`.
4. If the two match, it'll trigger a `showHeadline` callback function.

**BUT**... you would still have to compensate for the CSS `transition` delay (which is why the `showHeadline` callback function is delayed by 3500ms)!

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Transition Component]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a counter and a listener.When the  animation of one word ends, count +1 and listen whether the count equals to the words length. If equal, run `this.state.showHeadline`.